# How to create a styled console output like facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I just opened the dev tools from chrome and see something like this..

[image: styled console]

Have anyone create a styled log?

Comment: All you had to do to find the duplicate was to type your question title into google ... so please make a minimal effort before asking next time, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log("%c%s output: %d", "color:red; background:blue; font-size: 16pt", 'Facebook', 100);
```